# Is possible to build a Linux network over fibre channel NICs?

Tags: networking

I want to speed up my Linux network between two computers by using fibre channel cards and a direct connection between them.

I was not sure if my network cards supported that but I did a bit of digging and I think they should support that kind of networking. Here my NICs models:
Qlogic QLE2562 and Qlogic QLE2460

Searching on Google resulted in IPFC, but it seems to be not supported in Linux any more (and for quite some time as well).
Has anyone ever got that working?
Or am I thinking wrong?
Does anyone have at least some keywords for me to dig around further?

My goal is to have some kind of network interfaces that I can use to rsync files over or something like that. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Probably not. Everybody dropped support for IPFC a decade ago and I wouldn't count on it coming back. Just go get proper Ethernet cards.

Comment: I know IPFC is dropped in support, but is there no way to get networking working over fibre channel cards?

Comment: Again, **I wouldn't count on it coming back.**

Comment: I found the answer on superuser.com - https://superuser.com/questions/1703289/how-do-i-set-up-a-fibre-channel-hba-adapter-as-a-network-device